# How to do Google REST drive API batch request

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I'm currently building an android app which lets the user to browse through a **public shared google drive folder**, the problem is that when a folder contains a large amount of files(<100), app gets too much time to get their metadata. 
What i'm do now is first retrieve the file ID's in the folder, then in a for loop I just request for metadata. So it's one by one getting the data.

Is it okay to use Threads for every 10 files? So I will have 5 Threads if the total files I have to retrieve information is 50. Is this a good approach or can I use batchrequest?

Can I use BatchRequest to do this? I can't understand how to use this properly.
[BachRequest](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch)

Comment: `BatchRequest`s will indeed reduce the overhead you have with creating and sending API requests. They won't reduce quota usage or rate limit counts.  Consider shrinking the size of your responses through the use of partial responses (review the API documentation page/guide on best practices). For an example, does the [Java example at the bottom of the page you linked](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#using-client-libraries) not suffice?

Comment: @tehhowch well I have a bunch of file ID's and I can't just figure out how to use them with BatchRequest

Comment: Don't use BatchRequest - it really is not worth the pain. Do as tehhowch says and request the minimum fields. You can also reduce the page size of the list so it retrieves say 50 files in each HTTP GET. Your approach of getting each file individually is not a good one.